# Swift - access UIImagePickerController from modal view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to `present` an `UIImagePickerController` from inside a modal view?

In my case I have a `class` called `MakeWishView` which is a `UIView` and the user should be able to pick an image if he taps on a `button` inside the `MakeWishView`. My problem right now is that I can not call `present` because `MakeWishView` is not a `ViewController` but a `UIView`.

This is what I would like to call:

```
@objc private func wishImageButtonTapped(){
    showImagePickerController()
    print("wishImageButtonTapped")
}

// image picker
extension MakeWishView: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @objc func showImagePickerController(){
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil) // -> error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a delegate to the presenting vc like

```
 class MakeWishView:UIView {
    weak var delegate:VCName?
```

or

```
 let root = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController
 root.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: right, I think a delegate will do the job. How does your 2nd option work? Never seen that before

Comment: 2nd options gets the root vc of the app